# I cannot include my own libft.h and i don't know why

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I want to include in a random test.c file my own library to test if it works but I can't do it.
Even a simple make all doesn't work, but I'm supposed to have done everything right. I have the impression that my makefile doesn't even compile my .c files in .o
here is my make file:

```
SRCS    = ft_atoi.c ft_isascii.c ft_memchr.c ft_putchar_fd.c ft_strchr.c ft_strlen.c ft_strtrim.c \
ft_bzero.c ft_isdigit.c ft_memcmp.c ft_putendl_fd.c ft_strdup.c ft_strmapi.c ft_substr.c \
ft_calloc.c ft_isprint.cft_memcpy.c ft_putnbr_fd.c ft_strjoin.c ft_strncmp.c ft_tolower.c \
ft_isalnum.c ft_itoa.c ft_memmove.c ft_putstr_fd.c ft_strlcat.c ft_strnstr.c ft_toupper.c \
ft_isalpha.c ft_memccpy.c ft_memset.c ft_split.c ft_strlcpy.c ft_strrchr.c \
\
CC  = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
HEADER  = libft.h
OBJS    = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
RM  = rm -f
NAME    = libft.a

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o ${<:.c=.o}

$(NAME):    $(OBJS) $(HEADER)
        ar rcs $(NAME) $(OBJS)

all:        $(NAME)

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJS)

fclean:     clean
        $(RM) $(NAME)

re:     fclean all
.PHONY:     all clean fclean re
```

Comment: There's a stray backslash at the end of SRCS, but it isn't the cause of your trouble.  You.might need to specify `-I.` especially if you use `#include <libft.h>`.

Comment: `ft_isprint.cft_memcpy.c` - missing a space?